# Wrong offset from ZoneId?

Tags: java, timezone

```
ZoneId.of("Australia/ACT").getRules().getOffset(LocalDateTime.of(2019, 03, 31, 13, 0, 0, 0))
```

Returns

```
+11:00
```

Which appears to be incorrect according to [timeanddate](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20190331T130000&p1=tz_gmt&p2=tz_act-australia)

I expect +10:30 offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Australia/ACT` is an old deprecated name in the [IANA database (*tzdata*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) and does not refer to [Australian Central Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/act-australia).  It instead refers to [Australian Capital Territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Capital_Territory), which is in the same time zone as [Sydney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney).

Try `Australia/Adelaide` or `Australia/Broken_Hill` for time zones refering to [Australian Central Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/act-australia).

Example code.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of ( 2019 , 03 , 31 , 13 , 0 , 0 , 0 );
System.out.println ( "Offsets for: " + ldt );

List < ZoneId > zones = 
        List.of ( 
            ZoneId.of ( "Australia/Adelaide" ) , 
            ZoneId.of ( "Australia/Broken_Hill" ) 
        )
;
for ( ZoneId zone : zones )
{
    ZoneOffset offset = zone.getRules ().getOffset ( ldt );
    System.out.println ( "zone: " + zone.toString () + " has offset: " + offset.toString () );
}
```

When run in Java 13 (from AdoptOpenJDK):

> Offsets for: 2019-03-31T13:00
>
> zone: Australia/Adelaide has offset: +10:30
>
> zone: Australia/Broken_Hill has offset: +10:30

Tip: For full list of real time zones, consult a fresh copy of [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). More conveniently, consult [Wikipedia for a list of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), though the list may be outdated.